# Взаимодействие с моделями Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Имеется функция, выводящая выборку постов

```
 public function sold(){
        $post=Posts::where('amount', '=', 0)->where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(5);
        return $post->title;
        $purchase=Purchase::where('post_id','=', $post->id);
        $post->purchasedate=$purchase->created_at;

        return view('home')->withPost($post);
    }
```

При попытке вызова я получаю ошибку, т.к. не могу использовать `$post->id` для присоединения к выборке результатов из др. таблицы. Как мне это грамотно реализовать? Отношения между моделями установлены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в моделях связь установлена, то остается просто вызвать это отношение, к примеру в модели Posts у тебя такое отношение

```
public function purchases() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Purchase', 'id', 'post_id')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

Тогда в методе `sold` нужно использовать такую конструкцию:

**upd после комментариев**

```
$post=Posts::where([
                     ['amount', '=', 0],
                     ['user_id','=', Auth::user()->id]
                   ])->with('purchases')->paginate(5);
```

а в `blade` используешь `{{$post->purchases[0]->created_at}}`

p.s. чуть переделал `where`, так симпатичнее

Comment: Проблема действительно в связи была) но не совсем так, как вы сказали. Есть еще 1 вопрос - у меня в модели Purchases есть поле user_id - человек совершивший покупку, Могу ли я в этом же запросе вытянуть его параметры по id?

Comment: @RedScreed, ну вот сложно без полного кода и понятия структуры таблицы говорить точно что и как у вас:) так что ссори, да конечно можно так

Comment: где у вас связь прописана, аля `hasOne("...")->with('user')`, а эта связь должна уже быть у вас, где `user` имя связи в вашей модели

Comment: В отдельный вопрос это оформил

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67712/discussion-on-answer-by-maxkrasnov----laravel).